# Skip the sentence that has certain first word

Tags: php

I want to check the first word of some sentences. If the first word are `For`, `And`, `Nor`, `But`, `Or`, etc, I want to skip the sentence.

Here's the code :

```
<?php
  $sentence = 'For me more';
  $arr = explode(' ',trim($sentence));
  if(stripos($arr[0],'for') or stripos($arr[0],'but') or stripos($arr[0],'it')){
    //doing something
  }
?>
```

Blank result, Whats wrong ? thank you :)

Comment: Define what you mean by sentence.  You mean a single string that is to be evaluated, or will you be trying to parse through a large set of text, trying to determine where sentences begin? Regardless, your best bet is probably you use a regular expression.

Comment: @MikeBrant I wanna try to parse through a large set of text, But I wanna trying in single sentence first.

Answer (score 2):

Here, `stripos` will return 0 if the word is found (found at position 0).

It returns false if the word is not found.

You should write :

```
if(stripos($arr[0],'for') !== false or stripos($arr[0],'but') !== false or stripos($arr[0],'it') !== false){ 
  //skip 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stripos returns the position on the first occurrence of the needle in the haystack
The first occurrence is at position 0, which evaluates to false.

Try this as an alternative

```
$sentence = 'For me more';

// make all words lowercase
$arr = explode(' ', strtolower(trim($sentence)));

if(in_array($arr[0], array('for', 'but', 'it'))) {
   //doing something
   echo "found: $sentence";
} else {
   echo 'failed';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use `preg_filter` if you are going to know what the string to be evaluated is (i.e. you don't need to parse out sentences).

```
$filter_array = array(
    '/^for\s/i',
    '/^and\s/i',
    '/^nor\s/i',
    // etc.
}

$sentence = 'For me more';

$result = preg_filter(trim($sentence), '', $filter_array);

if ($result === null) {
    // this sentence did not match the filters
}
```

This allows you to determine a set of filter regex patterns to see if you have a match.  Note that in this case I just used `''` as "replacement" value, as you don't really care about actually making a replacement, this function just gives you a nice way to pas in an array of regular expressions.

Comment: Should the patterns have a trailing SPACE after the word, to ensure you match on For instead of words like Forever

Comment: yes.. that was definitely an oversight on my part. This has been corrected.